# can I add node and express to existing shopify website that is not created via shopify partners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, shopify, liquid

I am trying to determine if I can create a node and express built as part of server back end for an existing shopify website built using a regular shopify theme.  I would like to do that so I can use forwarding email that nodejs can provide.

Comment: We are many to know nodejs+express, and few to know shopify. So can you show us what you have tried, if you want nodejs to serve shopify, or the other way round?

Comment: Well, I have a client that allowed me access to his shopify website.  It is using liquid templating engine.  It is comprises of more than 30  files that are programmed shopify code base.  I cant show you the code here.  But I can send you to theme kit I had set up to be able to edit the code on my local machine using visual studio.   Going back to the original question, I am just asking knowledgeable people out there who have tried that perhaps and lead me to the right direction.  lmk.

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question. What are you trying to achieve with Node/Express?

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself a partner account. It is free. Make yourself an App in Shopify for your client, in your partner account dashboard.

Use the Shopify App credentials you just made, with your Node/Express App to add yourself to your customer's shop.

Profit. It is really that simple.

Comment: David, I knew that.  I was wondering if we can add node/express to an existing shopify theme that wasnt created via `shopify partners`

Comment: what? why can't you create a partner account and use it? Are you deep into some sheeeet?

Comment: LOL, no David, I was hired to modify a clients already existing account.  I think I did a workaround it and I got it done.  But I think the answer to my original question is "NO".  But thanks man.

Comment: Lets see if there is a master coder somewhere out there that have dealt with this.  I think the person who knows this maybe a shopify tech.  So much restrictions on shopify.

Comment: That is pretty funny. Yes the answer was no. And yes, my answer was correct. And since you have no confidence in your workaround, I am almost certain it is because not only do you not need a master coder to implement my solution, but your workaround (which probably ignored my advice) is probably either leaving your client wide open to abuse or suffering from some fracture...

Comment: didnt say I wasnt confident with my approach.  I just have a mentality that theres always an optimal way of doing things.  I just wondered if there are other people who's been in the same boat.  It would be nice to hear em.  Thats all.